# Use induction to show that if $n\geq 0$ then $5^n\equiv 1+4n\pmod{16}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, induction

I was checking the following number theory exercise:

> Use induction to show that if $n\geq 0$ then 
>   $5^n\equiv 1+4n\pmod{16}$

Applying the induction hypotesis I'm starting from here:

$16\mid 5^{n+1}-5-4n$

I don't know how to proceed from there or to go ahead in the exercise, any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Is the expression $5n\equiv 1+4n\pmod {16}$, or something else?

Comment: "Applying the induction hypot(h)esis I'm starting from here..." Sorry but somebody should revise extremely seriously how proofs by induction work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume for some $n$,
$$5^n\equiv 4n+1\pmod{16}.$$
Then
$$5^{n+1}=5(5^n)\equiv5(4n+1)=20n+5\equiv4n+5=4(n+1)+1\pmod{16}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$5^{n+1}-5-4n- 5 \cdot (5^n-1-4n)=16n$$